# How are search engine able to find and locate products within a webpage?

Tags: html, single-page-application, server-side-rendering, search-engine, multi-page-application

If I am not mistaken when a request is made on the Amazon site (multi-page application), an html is generated using the database in the server.

For example, products are constantly added and removed from/to the amazon database.

Since the HTML can only be generated using the amazon database - this is all dynamic and constantly changing, how is google searches able to provide me a link for a product in Amazon?

For instance, a search of "HTML, XHTML and CSS For Dummies, 7th Edition" will give me the image below:[image]

Does Google query the product in Amazon.com (and countless other webpages) and when it finds that the products exist (when it receives an HTML back), it then serves me the results in the search engine?

Answer (score -1):

Google knows the link because the product is internally linked in the Amazon website, for instance in "latest additions" or "you may also be interested in these other products".